# audio features extraction using restricted boltzmann machine

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, speech-processing

I want to extract Audio Features using RBM (Restricted Boltzmann Machine). For this, I am giving the spectrogram (PCA whitened) as an input to the RBM. For each audio file, The spectrogram is a matrix with no. of columns fixed but with different number of rows for each audio file. My question how can I train my RBM, or how can I extract the features from audio using RBM, given this spectrogram matrix. I read in a paper by Honglak Lee, paper title Unsupervised Feature Learning for Audio Classification using convolutional deep belief networks.
http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2009_1171.pdf
"We then trained 300 first layer bases with a filter length of 6 and a max-pooling ratio of 3."
First, what is meant by bases here. (They have used Convolutional Deep Belief Networks, so I guess, bases do not mean weights here).
Second, what do they mean by using a filter length of 6? How can I do it? Any hint will be appreciated. (I am new to RBM)

Comment: It depends on the purpose of your features. What will you use them for (speaker recognition, artist recognition, speech recognition and so on).

Comment: I am using it for speaker recognition (say). The goal later on is to use it for speaker recognition, and speech recognition as well.